# About Arrays and functions in C

Tags: c

In C, if you pass an array as an argument to a function, what actually gets passed? And Why?

Answer (score 0):

See the standard.

On entry to the function, the size expressions of each variably modified parameter are
evaluated and the value of each argument expression is converted to the type of the
corresponding parameter as if by assignment. (Array expressions and function
designators as arguments were converted to pointers before the call.)